# Find value of a key within array of arrays and keep array which contains this value

Tags: angular, typescript

I have interface:

```
export interface IProfileInterface {
  profilePic: string;
  profileName: string;
  profileRank: number;
  profilePoints: number;
  profileTasksDone: number;
  profileRankChange: number;
}
```

Service:

```
  getRanking(): IProfileInterface[] {
    return [
      {
        profilePic: 'assets/1.jpg',
        profileName: 'Adam',
        profileRank: 3,
        profilePoints: 120,
        profileTasksDone: 3,
        profileRankChange: 5,
      },
      {
        profilePic: 'assets/2.jpg',
        profileName: 'Bart',
        profileRank: 1,
        profilePoints: 130,
        profileTasksDone: 4,
        profileRankChange: 1,
      },
      {
        profilePic: 'assets/3.jpg',
        profileName: 'Mom',
        profileRank: 2,
        profilePoints: 100,
        profileTasksDone: 2,
        profileRankChange: -2,
      },
```

Now im my component i need to get only

```
{
        profilePic: 'assets/2.jpg',
        profileName: 'Bart',
        profileRank: 1,
        profilePoints: 130,
        profileTasksDone: 4,
        profileRankChange: 1,
      },
```

basing on **profileRank**.

In other words, I need to find array where **profileRank** key has value `1` and save this whole array to variable.

I know I could achieve this by just iterating through all arrays but I'll be having many arrays in DB so this won't be efficient. Is there any other possibility?

Comment: Build an object mapping the lookup value to the corresponding object.

Comment: not sure how to do that

Comment: Well that's something to research at least, it's going to be hard to work in Angular without basic JS knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

Got it with
`this.keys_first = this.ranking_data.filter(item => item["profileRank"] === 1)`